# why TypeScript doesn't support Type.property in addtion to Type['property']

Tags: typescript

why TypeScript doesn't support `Type.property` in addtion to [lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) like `Type['property']`

I find the former much more readable, but I guess there must be a reason why it's not supported.

---

for reference, here are two issues in which this is discussed

the TLDR version is that it would conflict with namespaces

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30815
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12962

it's real shame both issues have been closed.

Comment: Here's the relevant github issue where this is discussed. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30815

Comment: thanks Alex, if you want to inlude your comment as an answer I would be happy to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Typescript maintainer Ryan Cavanaugh, this is working as intended.

See this GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30815